# Maven install command doesn't build anything but it shows build success

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium

The console message from IDE is:

```
Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ maven ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Documents and Settings\ grandcanyonlab \Desktop \workspace  \selenium_mvn_googlesearch \target\maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ maven ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Documents and  Settings \grandcanyonlab \Desktop \workspace \selenium_mvn_googlesearch\target\maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Documents and Settings \grandcanyonlab\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Documents and Settings \grandcanyonlab \Desktop \workspace \selenium_mvn_googlesearch\pom.xml to C:\Documents and Settings\grandcanyonlab\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-0.0.1-  SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.360s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 07 17:25:31 PDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My POM.XML File is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org 
/2001 /XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http:  //maven.apache.org /xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>maven</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.43.0</version>  
</dependency> 
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.11</version>
```

It shows Build success but doesn't have the Test Run set to 1. It says 0. and I am not able to find the .jar file in the target folder. It shows the mycompany.app.Apptest . Am I doing anything wrong while compiling the code?

Comment: Have you checked the jars here : C:\Documents and Settings \grandcanyonlab\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. Otherwise do mvn package, it will create jar and put it into target folder.

Comment: Yes, I have maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar in that location. But When trying to execute through command prompt, it says : Using eclipse workspace : null. Also where can I find maven settings.xml file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sometimes eclipse doesn't udpate these jars(using m2 plugin). Try to do update it manually, select project and click on Alt + f5. It is nothing to do with settings.xml. Default settings.xml can be found in installationfolder/conf. You can customize it and put it in your .m2 folder.

Comment: can u plase here the full pom.xml? the one that i see here is incomplete and invalid (missing tags)

Comment: I did edit the pom.xml file, for some reason, it is not showing the last two tags. The last two tags are <dependency>.

Comment: @Bala : Thanks the update is working,But it still throws the build successful message but the test Run is set to 0. and in the target folder, the jar file which is getting created is for the default mycompany.app.AppTest. I dont have a main method in my class as i have used the annotations, is it because of that?

Comment: do u have a parent pom, and u removed it in the edit? or do you have something like <packaging>pom</packaging> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you try to build the main maven project: `org.apache.maven.maven:<version>`.

Note that this project is by default only a pom, not a JAR. Meaning, `<packaging>pom</packaging>`.
Why do you try to rebuild maven? Is it on purpose? If not, change your groupId/ArtifactId... and make sure that `<packaging>jar</packaging>`.

HTH

Comment: That helped! I am able to create a jar file. But the project has a sign telling error, but no errors are to be found.In dependencies, the junit and selenium have a red line but no error.